# Why is datasource handling in query different from handling it in a form?

Tags: axapta

I am trying to rewrite some form to the lisp page template. In a list page you must use query as a datasource. I have datasource structure in previous (without list page template) and a new one with list page template. But I am now facing a fact that handling datasource in form is different than handling it in a query.

Can someone explayin why it is done this way and how to make a query so there will be almost no difference between datasource before and after using list page template?

For example I have DSs Object, Sub-Object1, Sub-Object2. 
Sub-Object1 have a jointSource Object in properties with exist joint and Sub-Object1 have jointSource Object with Inner Join.

Is there some way to set this in [Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb314753.aspx) DS properties or I must add 
[datasource to datasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh803130.aspx)  and link in more manually.

Comment: I do not wish to make form with same DS as a query. I am trying to make a query which will have "same" DS as a form has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well mayby because a form need more information than query?

If you do have a query already.you can drag it to your form as a datasource.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg844014.aspx

Comment: I am making form with "list page" template so the query is only datasource I can use. The previous form (which I am trying to copy but with list page template) is not list page and do not use query as datasource.

Comment: @jan-b-kjeldsen I forget to mention you in previous comment.

Comment: Then change the "previous form" to use the Query.

Comment: @jan-b-kjeldsen I am not sure if I am clear enough. I have a (normal) form which is doing something and "only thing" I want to do is recreate it with "list page" template. I am facing some problems because the "list page" template forbid many things that can be done on a form without template.

Answer (score 0):

The same effect as a datasource with join type in properties can be done on query by using related datasources. So on the query the structure will be more readable than structure on normal form datasources.